# How to connect server to Xmmp server

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am trying to connect my server to jabber client IOS server but did not connecting?

I am trying below code for connection.

```
NSString *presenceType = [presence type]; // online/offline
NSString *myUsername = [[sender myJID] user];
NSString *presenceFromUser = [[presence from] user];

if (![presenceFromUser isEqualToString:myUsername]) {

    if ([presenceType isEqualToString:@"available"]) {

        [_chatDelegate newBuddyOnline:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@", presenceFromUser, @""]];

    } else if ([presenceType isEqualToString:@"unavailable"]) {

        [_chatDelegate buddyWentOffline:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@", presenceFromUser, @"YOURSERVER"]];

    }

}
```

But its not working for me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

First make sure your users and passwords were created correctly in your Server. Second check the "Server Name" property if it was set correctly. Go to you admin panel -> Server Information -> Server Name. If this property is not set to "john-imac.local.lan" then your server will fail in authorizing your users. To set it up pressed on the Edit properties button and change the name of your sever.

I hope this helps you solving the problem you are having!

Good Luck !!!

Enjoy Programming !!!